# Power BI - Transform line into column

Tags: powerbi, transform, powerquery

I new to use the KPI form on Power BI, but I have the same target for all the months for each KPI in one single line like this:

```
Month         ResultKPI1   ResultKPI2 ResultKPI3
1/1/2020      90%          88%        87%
2/1/2020      91%          93%        89%
3/1/2020      89%          87%        95%
Target        90%          95%        93%
```

To use the KPI Forms from Power BI, I need to transform on Power Query the "Target" line into one column for each "ResultKPI" column, with the respective value on each line, like this:

```
Month         ResultKPI1 TargetKPI1 ResultKPI2 TargetKPI2 ResultKPI3 TargetKPI3
1/1/2020      90%          90%      88%        95%        87%        93%
2/1/2020      91%          90%      93%        95%        89%        93%
3/1/2020      89%          90%      87%        95%        95%        93%
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerQuery, duplicate the data source.

Filter the data source in to two tables:

1. Target
2. Results

Add an index / base column to both with a fixed value of 1.

Use the merge function in PowerQuery to OUTER join the tables together again (on the base column), then expand the Target table in the results.

It's a bit tricky, so I did a quick example.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In this way you can merge the targets in to results so that you get the view in your second table.